# Tomcat doesn't start my web service

Tags: web-services, tomcat, jakarta-ee, tomcat7, cxf

I have created a web service using [Spring, Apache Cxf, Tomcat, intellij Idea]
After I config tomcat and run it. I get this
[image: Output log on console]
My web service:
[image: My web service class]
web.xml:
[image: web.xml]
Spring appContext:
[image: Spring-applicationContext]

Comment: Can you please post your tomcat logs error ?

Comment: I solve my log4j problem, now the real exception is: nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching   wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element <jaxws

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be missing the proper configuration for the xsd for the CXF tags. You should have the following pair in your config file:

```
http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd
```

So, in combination, you'll have

```
<xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">
```

Also, ensure you have the necessary dependencies for the CXF frontend tags, specifically: *cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws.jar*

Comment: the problem was lack of http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd in my SpringAppContext, Thanks @kolossus